# AJAX not rendering update prior to manual page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working through *Agile Web Development with Rails 4*, stuck on Chapter 11, Iteration F4. The goal of the section is to have a shopping cart div display only when there are items in the cart, otherwise hide it via `display: none`. The cart does properly hide itself when the Empty Cart button is clicked, but when an item is then added to it, the cart doesn't display unless the page is then manually refreshed.

Here's what the server output looks like when an item is added to an empty cart:

```
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=2" for ::1 at 2015-05-10 18:51:44 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"v2zcRr2CPsfZP3/qI8l5m0HWdDoOiiyl5oiZxvpYKXp7K2ecXizzCZA37DLm7PwYuSAgemogwjjnDHz4NbavGA==", "product_id"=>"2"}
  Cart Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  LineItem Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ? AND "line_items"."product_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["cart_id", 21], ["product_id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "line_items" ("product_id", "cart_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["product_id", 2], ["cart_id", 21], ["created_at", "2015-05-11 01:51:44.341300"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-11 01:51:44.341300"]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 21]]
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered line_items/_line_item.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (6.7ms)
  Rendered line_items/create.js.erb (8.9ms)
```

And here's what the output looks like when I refresh:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-05-10 18:57:17 -0700
Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
  Cart Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
  Product Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  ORDER BY "products"."updated_at" DESC LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  ORDER BY "products"."title" ASC
  Rendered store/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.9ms)
  LineItem Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["cart_id", 21]]
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?  [["cart_id", 21]]
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered line_items/_line_item.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (6.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 129ms (Views: 124.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

Here's my LineItemsController, containing the `create` action triggered when I add the item to the empty cart:

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_line_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /line_items
  # GET /line_items.json
  def index
    @line_items = LineItem.all
  end

  # GET /line_items/1
  # GET /line_items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /line_items/new
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end

  # GET /line_items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /line_items
  # POST /line_items.json
  def create
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url }
        format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /line_items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.update(line_item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item, notice: 'Line item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /line_items/1
  # DELETE /line_items/1.json
  def destroy
    @line_item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_line_item
      @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def line_item_params
      params.require(:line_item).permit(:product_id)
    end
end
```

And this is my StoreController, containing the `index` action triggered by the manual refresh:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart

  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
  end
end
```

It seems that when I empty the cart and inspect the div, the `display: none` attribute is applied (as it should be) from application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class='<%= controller.controller_name %>'>
  <div id="banner">
    <%= image_tag("logo.png") %>
    <%= @page_title || "Pragmatic Bookshelf" %>
  </div>
  <div id="columns">
    <div id="side">
      <%= hidden_div_if(@cart.line_items.empty?, id: 'cart') do %>
        <%= render @cart %>
      <% end %>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www....">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../faq">Questions</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www..../Contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `hidden_div_if` method is in ApplicationHelper.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def hidden_div_if(condition, attributes = {}, &block)
    if condition
      attributes["style"] = "display: none"
    end
    content_tag("div", attributes, &block)
  end
end
```

But when I inspect the cart div after adding an item, `display: none` is still applied. What am I missing?

If it matters, here's my CartsController:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to store_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end
    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Invalid cart'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days of spinning my wheels, I finally noticed that the jQuery selectors in my create.js.erb were missing the `#`, i.e.:

```
if ($('cart tr').length == 1) {
  $('cart').show('blind', 1000);
}
```

Instead of:

```
if ($('#cart tr').length == 1) {
  $('#cart').show('blind', 1000);
}
```

Adding them fixed it.